# Intent to Google Navigation for itinerary with several waypoints

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-urls

I want to know, if it's possible to put several "checkpoints" within "Google Navigation" (Google Maps Navigation) With a query that follows the next syntax : `"google.navigation:q=44.871709,-0.505704...."`

If it possible, what is the syntax for separate two points ?

For one point it works, example : `"google.navigation:q=44.871709,-0.505704"`

But I would put a few checkpoints for example :

```
 LatLng point1 = new LatLng(44.871709,-0.505704);
 LatLng point2 = new LatLng(43.572665,3.871447);                    
 Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+
 point1.latitude+","+point1.longitude+";"+ point2.latitude+","+point2.longitude));
```

I read others issues, they say to use this syntax :

```
"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+"44.871709,-0.505704"+"&daddr="+"43.572665,3.871447"
```

With above solution, "Google Navigation" is not started automatically, we must choose one application "Google Maps" and next, to click on Itinerary (in top of the screen) to start "Google Navigation".
I would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a way to supress the dialog and go to maps directly.

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+"44.871709,-0.505704"+"&daddr="+"43.572665,3.871447";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Let me know if you still have issues.

**UPDATE**

As of May 2017, there is a better approach, the Google Maps URLs API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Using this API you can construct an URL with origin, destination and waypoints and pass it to the intent

```
String uri = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Madrid,Spain&destination=Barcelona,Spain&waypoints=Zaragoza,Spain%7CHuesca,Spain&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I think I'll give up my idea and keep your solution thank you ;-)

Comment: Is there any way to add features like "Avoid Highways" in this URL?

Comment: Is there any way to add flag to cancel any ongoing navigation?

Comment: what if GoogleMaps not installed on device?

Comment: can i put onActivityResult on this intent ? because i want kilometer from that live navigation.

Answer (score 3):

Check these 2 methods, both of them work properly for me.

**METHOD 1:**

```
    String packageName = "com.google.android.apps.maps";
    String query = "google.navigation:q=49.4839509,8.4903999";

    Intent intent = this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(query));
    startActivity(intent);
```

**METHOD 2:**

```
    String packageName = "com.google.android.apps.maps";
    String query = "google.navigation:q=49.4839509,8.4903999";

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(query));
    intent.setPackage(packageName);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because point1.longitude is Double,you should use this

```
String.valueOf(point1.latitude);

Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+String.valueOf(point1.latitude)+","+String.valueOf(point1.longitude)+";"+String.valueOf( point2.latitude)+","+String.valueOf(point2.longitude)));
```

Or you can use this,but it is just the same.

```
point1.toString().replace("lat/lng: (", "").replace(")", "")
```

point1.toString() the result is "lat/lng: (44.871709,-0.505704)",remove the "lat/lng: (" and ")".
then you can get the result that you want.

```
Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+point1.toString().replace("lat/lng: (", "").replace(")", "")+"&daddr="+point2.toString().replace("lat/lng: (", "").replace(")", "")));
```

Or you can try this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/mapssaddr="+point1.toString().replace("lat/lng: (", "").replace(")", "")+"&daddr="+point2.toString().replace("lat/lng: (", "").replace(")", ""));
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I try this but GoogleNav. still does not understand this itinerary.  Thank you anyway for your help ;-)

Comment: in google.navigation:q= doesn't understand ; between multiple latlng

Answer (score -1):

You have to just pass destination location. Google Maps app will automatically take your current location for navigation.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + String.valueOf(destination latitude)
                        + "," + String.valueOf(destination longitude)));

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: the question is about specifying _multiple_ locations, not one.